# Many definitions of Hochschild homology and cyclic homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, big-list, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology

It appears that there are more definitions of cyclic homology than there are people working on cyclic homology. As a newcomer, this confuses me to no end. I've written a list of definitions that some Google searches have given me, although I am confident that there are many more. My **question** is essentially: what is the relation between all of them?

- If $A$ is an associative algebra over a ring $k$, then it has a Hochschild complex $C_*(A)$ with differential $b$, whose homology is called **Hochschild homology**. If one instead quotients out by the cyclic permutation on the level of complexes, one obtains **cyclic homology** $HC_*(A)$ of $A$. If one moreover has an ideal $I$ of $A$, we can define **relative cyclic homology** $HC_*(A,I)$ to be the homology groups of the complex $\operatorname{ker}(C_*(A) \to C_*(A / I))$.
- One can also define **Hochschild homology** of an associative $k$-algebra $A$ to be $\operatorname{Tor}_*^{A \otimes A^{\text{op}}}(A,A)$.
- If $A$ is an associative algebra over a ring $k$, one can instead define an additional operator $B$ on $C_*(A)$, forming a double complex. The homology of the total complex should be **cyclic homology**. From this point of view, it appears that one can work more generally with bimodules over $A$.
- Letting $A$ again be an associative algebra over a ring $k$, one can also define $CC_*(A)$ to be the complex $C_*(A)[[u^{\pm 1}]] / u C_*(A)[[u]]$ with operator $b + u B$. The homology of this complex is **cyclic homology**. In addition, **negative cyclic homology** is obtained from the complex $C_*(A)[[u]]$ with differential $b + uB$, and **periodic cyclic homology** is obtained from $C_*(A)[[u^{\pm 1}]]$ with operator $b + uB$.
- In addition, I've read somewhere that we can view cyclic homology as being a derived functor on $(b,B)$-complexes, but I do not understand what that means.
- If $A$ is an associative, unital ring, one can consider the simplicial object formed by $A^{\otimes n}$, and the geometric realisation should somehow be **Hochschild homology** of $A$. This admits an $S^1$-action, and **cyclic homology** is defined by taking homotopy orbits, while **negative cyclic homology** is defined via homotopy fixed points.
- Connes has defined a **cyclic homology** theory in terms of what is called cyclic vector spaces. Cyclic homology can then be computed as certain Ext-groups. I have also been told that there is a categorical way of defining cyclic homology in terms of cyclic objects. I do not know if this is the same thing.
- Charles Weibel has defined **cyclic homology** for schemes in terms of hypercohomology, so this in particular applies to the case of commutative rings and algebras.
- In a derived setting, **Hochschild homology** can be understood as the cohomology of a certain free loop space object, and **cyclic homology** is the corresponding equivariant cohomology.
- For C*-algebras, as far as I can tell the definitions can carry over, but I vaguely understand that there are many choices for the tensor product, which complicates matters. In addition, Wikipedia tells me that cyclic homology (in whatever form) of C*-algebras is degenerate as it cannot take into account the topological structure, and there are many variants to incorporate this topology. Mentioned there are **entire cyclic homology** due to Connes, **analytic cyclic homology** due to Meyer, **asymptotic cyclic homology** and **local cyclic homology** due to michael Puschnigg.
- Then there's **topological Hochschild homology** and **topological cyclic homology**, and it seems one could make equally long lists for them.

Comment: I can't answer everything, but for Hochschild homology, all definitions agree when $A$ is flat. When $A$ is not flat, all definitions agree if you derive everything in sight. I suspect the answer should be the same for cyclic homology