# Book recommendation for Cyclic Homology

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, hochschild-cohomology

I'm starting to learn what is Cyclic homology with the Loday's book "Cyclic Homology". It is a very well book for the technical part. However, I would like also to understand the intuition behind Cyclic homology, why Cyclic homology has been created, and his utility. Could someone recommend me good books please ?

Also, I heard that it was related to De Rham cohomology but I don't know what it is, I just had a quick introduction to differential geometry as part of a course.

Thank you.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461430/many-definitions-of-hochschild-homology-and-cyclic-homology) might be helpful, for all the different aspects and contexts of cyclic homology. There are many books on this topics. You have to focus on what you really want, or need.

Comment: Thank you, in fact I'm starting also to work on non-commutative geometry, so I would like a book that help me to develop the intuition and the link between Cyclic Homology and non-commutative geometry and i feel like the Loday's book doesn't do this. I found the Khalkhali's book "Basic Noncommutative Geometry" but I don't know if it does it well. Have you ever read it ?